# Error in opening .exe release file in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

When i run the .exe release file it shows some kind of awkward error in my IDE.
And when I try to run from outside the IDE as an appilcation it terminates as soon as it opens without showing any output.

I am using Eclipse and MinGw

[This is the error message my ide shows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmXFS.png)

And i guess there is nothing wrong with my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;  
    cout << "hello Again" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_it shows some kind of awkward error_" What is the error? And please remove the link to the 2nd error and include the error as text inside your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error, you are viewing the contents of the exe file which is not human-readable, but binary data. The output from your application is in the 'Console' window at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: You could specify that he's viewing *the contents* of the exe file, i.e. the real binary data inside it.